# Change the attribute of a method in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I want to make the method attributes changeable in Python 3, as Blueprint registration in Sanic sets `__blueprintname__` attribute on a route, and I want to use instance methods as routes.

The setup is simple:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        return 1

class B:
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        return 2

a = A()
a.test.attr = 1  # that throws AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'attr'

b = B()
b.test.attr = 2  # that works OK
```

Is there any particular reason why I can change the attribute of a static method, but can't do so to the regular one?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I described the reason at the beginning of a question. Sanic's Blueprint changes the attributes of a function passed to it, and I want to use instance methods as routes in Sanic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want to share some data and functions using the class

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It looks like `staticmethod` objects do support attribute assignment. It's the instance method that does not support attribute assignment from the OP's code.

Comment: @pomo_mondreganto Is using the class itself or an instance as routes an option?

Comment: Ah jeeze, yeah I read it backwards. It's the function obje t returned by the staticmethod that does support attribute assignment. The bound method object returned by the regular function descriptor doesnt

Comment: @oldwooki, I need to use instance's methods as routes

Comment: The question is more like "is there any reason for such constraints"

Comment: It's just how it's implemented. The fact that function objects support attribute assignment I'm not even sure is a language guarantee to begin with. The real question is why did Blueprint go with such a brittle design? Note, `a.test is not A.test`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [This section of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#index-33) guarantees that user-defined functions support attribute assignment. The following section specifies that methods support attribute access, but not assignment.